# Team Foundation Server - Viewing files in the last commit for a user

Tags: tfs

I want to know how to view a list of all files that was committed by a user **in their last commit.** Not all files committed by them just the ones which were committed in the last batch. For example, suppose I just committed 10 files in TFS and now I want to view the list of just those 10 files.

How do I do that?

Thanks,

-R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it.
Open any single file that you remember being part of the changeset in Visual Studio. Right click the file, go to source control and click on view history. Select the version you committed and right click then select view changeset details.

-R

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio 2010 you can also go to file, source control, changesets and search for changesets from this windows. You have the option of applying filter on changesets by users, or by date or by change set ids. Get the results and you can double click to see the files that are part of the changesets displayed in a new window.

Answer (score 1):

Or you install [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) and go over the shelveset sidekick menu and get [this screen](http://www.attrice.info/images/shelveset1_sk_screen.gif)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not free

Comment: The downloads are trial versions, see http://www.attrice.info/msbuild/license2.htm